# How to Mount Correctly an In-DOM Root Component Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vite

I have obviously a misconception of how the vue3 "In-DOM Root Component Template"-mechanism is working. Any hints appreciated!

I modified an example vite project to use "[In-DOM Root Component Template](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#in-dom-root-component-template)".

index.html

```
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div>
                <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/vite.svg" class="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <hello-world msg="Vite + Vue"></hello-world>
        </div>
        <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

const app = createApp({})

app.component('HelloWorld',HelloWorld)

app.mount('#app')
```

HelloWorld is the default example component, installed by vite install.

Result: The rendered output is empty, the div#app-innerHtml is not used as Template as expected.

Comment: Consider providing a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, these are the steps to reproduce the problem:
1. npm create vite@latest vitetest -- --template vue
2. cd vitetest
3. npm install
4. edit index.html (as shown above)
5. edit main.js (as shown above)
6. delete App.vue
7. npm run dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I had an js error here `const app = createApp()`

   Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render').

Vue Options should not be undefined. Please replace it with:

```
const app = createApp({})
```

2. You register you component in PascalCase as `HelloWorld` and use it the same way in HTML. But you should use kebab-case `<hello-world>`.

There is an explanation in the Vue Docs [Using a Component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component) about this:

> If you are authoring your templates directly in a DOM (e.g. as the
> content of a native  element), the template will be subject
> to the browser's native HTML parsing behavior. In such cases, you will
> need to use **kebab-case** and **explicit closing tag**s for components

Please pay attention to the **explicit closing tags** also.

The app works When you fix both problems. Here is the working playground

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-n2v2y4?file=public/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints and especially for the explanation - the playground is working with the suggested modifications - unexplainably there is no effect in my vite-setup. The rendered output is still empty. I edited the above code with your suggestions.

Comment: Then please check your logs and the browser console log for errors.

Comment: You can also try to replace the code in your setup with the code from sandbox. I guess  the Sandbox is also running on Vite. I have also deleted the style.css import, since there is no such file.

Comment: There were never errors in the console - but rechecking I turned on the warnings also and voila: [Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js". I'll try this one, everthing else should be fixed thanks to your answer!

Comment: Been ~10 hours struggling with this issue until I found this post. No errors in console nor compilation issues. Changing `import { defineComponent, ...} from 'vue'` to `import { defineComponent, ...} from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'` also worked for me. Thank you!